# A better way (or alternative) to calculate Pixel and % in CSS?

Tags: css, width, pixel

I'm not saying that I'm lazy to do math, but is there a better way to perform this task:
I have a page that with width: 960px, inside it has 2 divs that are width: 50%. That's quite simple, but if I want to add 1px border I have to calculate 960/0.5 minus the extra pixels of the borders, they should be 4px but strangely they are counted as 2px (left and right side of 2 divs right?). Also, when I add margin and padding I have to calculate everything again. Lets say I add 10px margin, I have to convert the % to px and sometimes it gives me annoying numbers like 760.25px. I would like to know if you are using a better approach or if its unnecessary to do it like this. Thanks.

Comment: why are you using % for, obviously, pixel perfection?

Comment: Pixel perfection is the root of all evil.

Comment: I'm the only pixel perfectionist around here?

Comment: People who use percentages and ems usually have extraordinarily unattractive websites. Take stackoverflow for instance; it's hideous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add more elements for sizing:

```
<div style="width:960px;overflow:hidden;">
  <div style="float:left;width:50%;">
    <div style="margin:5px;border:1px solid #000;padding:5px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left;width:50%;">
    <div style="margin:5px;border:1px solid #000;padding:5px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can use percentages for element with no margin, border or padding, and you can use margin, border and padding on the elements inside that has auto width.

Answer (score 2):

If you use fixed width of the container, why would you use % for inner DIV's. It does not make any sense unless you use percents. Sure you can use box-sizing, but it will hurt older browsers.

Comment: I don't get you very well. My idea is that those inner divs will accommodate using percentages according to their container's fixed width say 960px so that I don't have to do math with 960px all the time.

Answer (score 0):

box-sizing CSS property (if you dont care about IE<8)

Comment: I wish I didn't have to care but still have to for sake of accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

If your "divs" have a background image, you can hack by integrate the border in the background image.

But if your "divs" have a fixed width, you should calculate width in order to have no surprises with other web-browsers.